# YII2 mock web Request class in controller

Tags: yii2, mocking, phpunit, yii2-basic-app

In my yii2 controller I am running this:

```
$address = \Yii::$app->request->post('address');
```

How can I mock this request in PHPUnit? I've tried using mockery but cannot figure out how to mock the \Yii::$app part?

Answer (score 1):

to mock a request in Yii2 try this

```
use yii\web\Request;
use Codeception\Stub;

private function  mockRequest($attributes){
    // mock a request
    $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = 'http://localhost';
    $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1';
    \Yii::$app->requestedAction = new Action('fake', $this->model);
    \Yii::$app->setHomeUrl('http://localhost');
    return Stub::make(Request::class, [
        'getUserIP' =>'127.0.0.1',
        'enableCookieValidation' => false,
        'getUserAgent' => 'Dummy User Agent',
        'getBodyParams' => [
            'MyModel' => $attributes
        ],
    ]);
}
```

Comment: And then what? This is merely a copy paste from somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "then what"? Then you do whatever you need to do with the mocked request. Since we are talking testing I would suspect one would want to assert the result of the request. But that was not the question, was it? Everything is a copy of something (eg manuals etc). It's just an example of creating a request mock as was the question. Let me know what help you need with that!

Answer (score 1):

I struggled quite a bit with this one last week. I'm using Codeception, but I believe this will also work for PHPUnit, only needing minor adjustments.

Create a partial mock of the Request class and set it as active request inside your test:

```
$request = $this->createPartialMock('\yii\web\Request', ['getUserIP', 'getUserAgent', 'getBodyParams', 'getIsAjax']);

$request->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getIsAjax')
        ->will($this->returnValue(true));

$request->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getUserIP')
        ->will($this->returnValue('127.0.0.1'));

$request->expects($this->any())
        ->method('getUserAgent')
        ->will($this->returnValue('Dummy User Agent'));

\Yii::$app->set('request', $request);
```

[Source](https://vladimir-ivanov.net/mock-yii2-components/)